# 502 ERROR. CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I am deploying my node JS application to EC2. Everything to do with EC2 instance is working fine.
Now I want to enable only https requests to the app. I have configured a load balancer which I am configuring with cloud front to enable redirecting http to https requests. However, after running my app or the generated cloudfront DNS url I get the following error.

```
502 ERROR. the request could not be satisfied. CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
```

**Below are some few configurations I made:**

- I have configured my node JS API to AWS EC2.
- Created a load balancer for the EC2 instance which has a listener for http (port 80) and https (port 443). The http listener has a rule that redirects requests to the https listener.
- I have then configured cloudfront to redirect requests to the ALB. The cloud front also redirects http to https.
- My SSL certificate used for https requests registers 2 domains which have a similar format as the following; example.com and *.example.com.
- I then configured my domain in route 53 and aliased it to cloudfront

The ALB DNS Url is working when I run it on browser but when I run the my domain url or the cloudfront DNS url it gives me the above error.